# How to disable file download popup and save file directly to C drive

Tags: c#

My program generates doc file on browser and i want to save this file to my C drive dynamically

```
string filename = "fileName"; 
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= " + filename +".doc" );

Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word ";       
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
GridView1.DataBind();
GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: this is a nice requirement so what's the actual question and or Issue..?

Comment: want to save the file in C drive but it saves inside the download folder.

Comment: that depends on how the user set up his browser settings.

Comment: You can save a given location on the server, but you can't tell a client where to save a file in the HTTP response.  Beyond the security problems inherent in that approach, you have to take into account that there are a diverse array of clients with different file structures.  Even Windows clients do not necessarily have a C: drive.  A few ActiveX controls could allow you to dictate a save location, but those are client-side code and recent version of Internet Explorer intentionally make that difficult to implement.

Comment: Also, if the user is using some sort of download client, you can pre-populate a location, but if you don't know their file structure you're still going to have trouble.

Comment: @maniak1982: You should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @MikeGoodwin: Thanks.  I didn't know whether to do so, since it doesn't really answer the question so much as point out the problems with that approach.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot decide for the user where to save the file. User decides that.

Comment: Technically it is an answer because what the OP asks is impossible to achieve.

Comment: technically I guess ..but where does the OP specifically ask if it's possible or not.. I don't have jedi mind powers as you do @fsacer lol

Answer (score 1):

You can save a given location on the server, but you can't tell a client where to save a file in the HTTP response. Beyond the security problems inherent in that approach, you have to take into account that there are a diverse array of clients with different file structures. Even Windows clients do not necessarily have a C: drive. A few ActiveX controls could allow you to dictate a save location, but those are client-side code and recent version of Internet Explorer intentionally make that difficult to implement. Also, if the user is using some sort of download client, you can pre-populate a location, but if you don't know their file structure you're still going to have trouble.